# How can I access raw request xml from within a JAX Web Service?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I have an annotated JAX Web Service as such:

```
@WebMethod(action = "http://my.services/ITService/postIT")
@WebResult(name = "postITResponseTypeDef", targetNamespace = "http://my.services/ITService/", partName = "parameters")
public ResponseParameterList postIT(
    @WebParam(name = "postITRequestTypeDef", targetNamespace = "http://my.services/ITService/", partName = "parameters")
    PostITRequestTypeDef parameters,
    @WebParam(name = "ITHeaderTypeDef", targetNamespace = "http://my.services/ITService/", header = true, partName = "request_Header")
    ITHeaderTypeDef requestHeader)
    throws ITSoapException
;
```

In the class that implements this service I need to access the raw xml (preferably as a String) of the SOAP request.  How can I access that?

Thanks!

Comment: That is not a Spring Web Service that is a JAX-WS webservice.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum  I have corrected the title and text.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a SOAP message handler:

```
public class CustomAddressValidatorHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
   @Override
   public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
       ...
   } 
}
```

a handler-chain.xml file is needed to plug into the JAX-WS chain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<javaee:handler-chains 
     xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <javaee:handler-chain>
    <javaee:handler>
      <javaee:handler-class>package.handler.CustomAddressValidatorHandler</javaee:handler-class>
    </javaee:handler>
  </javaee:handler-chain>
</javaee:handler-chains>
```

And this applies the handler to a request:

```
@WebService
@HandlerChain(file="handler-chain.xml")
public class ServerInfo {
    ...
}
```

Also have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-server-side/).